# Play, seek a video in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, video-streaming

I want to play a video from Unity3D. The video play must be able to seek to a particular frame or time. Also I have a requirement of **playing the video from web**.

From Unity's documentation I am able to download an online video and play it as a movie texture. But I don't have the options to seek, fast forward etc. If you have any idea on that please let me know.

Or else suggest any libraries or plugins I can use to do this.

Thanks in advance.